# Use a hostname for a custom service

Tags: ddev

Is it possible to use use a hostname for a custom service. Currently, I have the following:

Redis service: `docker-compose.redis.yml`

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  redis:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-redis
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
      com.ddev.app-url: $DDEV_URL
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=$DDEV_HOSTNAME
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=6379
    volumes: []
  web:
    links:
      - redis:$DDEV_HOSTNAME
```

Redis Commander Service: `docker-compose.commander.yml`

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  redis:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-commander
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
      com.ddev.app-url: $DDEV_URL
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=$DDEV_HOSTNAME
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=8081
      - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
    volumes: []
  web:
    links:
      - commander:$DDEV_HOSTNAME
```

At the moment I can access the Redis Commander from the outside with `<project-name>.ddev.local:8081/`.

What I want to achieve, if possible is to access the Redis Commander from a custom hostname or subdomain like: `comander.<project-name>.ddev.local` or `commander.local`.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research and a lot of help from Randy Fay, we were able to accomplish it. We had to run the following:

`$ sudo ddev hostname commander.local 127.0.0.1`

The Redis Commander Service file(`docker-compose.commander.yml`) had to be updated to:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  commander:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-commander
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
      com.ddev.app-url: $DDEV_URL
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=commander.local
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=80
      - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
    volumes: []
  web:
    links:
      - commander:$DDEV_HOSTNAME
      - commander:commander.local
```

for it to work.